# I need to swap a colour with transparency

Tags: preview, catalina, image-editing

I have an image and I would like to be able to make white transparent, is this possible using Preview in Mac OSX Catalina?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preview is designed for viewing image files, making simple image adjustments, and annotations, not for full-on image editing. You cannot swap a color with transparency in Preview.

What you are looking to do could be accomplished in paid apps like [Adobe Photoshop](https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html) or free and open-source apps like [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/).

Depending on a number of different factors, like image type and compression, making white transparent in image editing software can be as simple as selecting all pixels of a single color and setting them to transparent, or as complex as manually selecting and setting pixels to transparent outside of an object's boundary.

Comment: Technically, you add data to the pixel's alpha channel, rather than 'removing' pixels.

Comment: @benwiggy Good point. I have made the change to the answer to reflect setting pixels to transparent instead of removing them.